# Paper_Trail and CanCan: Rails_Admin doesn't show versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I have configured Paper_Trail and CanCan in a Rails app. Rails_Admin shows me the tables `versions` and `version_associations` nicely.

In another app (which in fact is a fork of the previous one) I'd like Rails_Admin to show those tables, too, but it doesn't.

In both applications I am logged in as a user with role `admin`, and the ability for both apps looks like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(current_user)
    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, to: :crud

    can :read, User

    if current_user.nil?
      can :create, User
    else
      can :update, User do |user|
        user == current_user # Update himself
      end

      can :crud, Boilerplate # This is the only line that the 2nd app adds to the ability

      if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
        can :access, :rails_admin
        can :dashboard

        can :crud, :all
      end

      cannot :destroy, User do |user|
        user == current_user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Aside from the line `can :crud, Boilerplate`, all is the same. The migrations are the also the same, so I have the needed tables etc.

I have created a dump of each app's `current_ability`: [diff on diffchecker.com](https://www.diffchecker.com/7ygrzfji). What I can see is that the ability of the user which sees the Paper_Clip stuff in Rails_Admin has a lot of `@expanded_actions`, while the other one has not. Where could this come from? Both users definitely do have the `:admin` role.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't use the newest paper_trail version (version `4.0.0.rc`).